# Adding a library search path by target membership: how can I do it safely?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode you can add a library to a target Library Search Path either (1) manually from *Build Settings-->Library Search* Path or (2) by clicking on the target in the *Target Membership* pane once the library file is selected in the project navigation pane.

If you follow the quicker option (2) the library path is automatically added to *Build Settings-->Library* for you. However, if you then unselect the target, the corresponding *Build Settings-->Library Search Path* entry is not cleared out.

This can be quite error-prone. In fact, whenever you want to replace the library you are linking against with another one with the same name (for example you want to test the same library in release vs debug mode, or a different library version), it is easy to think you are linking to the new library whereas you are still linking to the old one.

Is there any trick for this?